# Stereo Headunit resets everytime its switched off/on

Tags: audio, wiring, head-unit

Car: Audi TT 2011
Stereo unit: Pioneer SPH DA120

New on here and dont usually need to ask but i cant find an answer to my problem anywhere.
Had a huge headache installing my head unit and a new sub today but whenever i take the key out the ignition and go to put it back in im welcomed by a language select screen and all settings have been restored.
I know that the yellow constant and red ignition wires are sometimes mixed up but i have tried swapping anyway which resulted in it looping from a loading screen to black screen, reeboots and cycles again continuously.

My multi meter was giving me 10V on my constant wire which made me think maybe it wasn't enough to keep it powered when it looses ignition. So i took a spare sub woofer power lead and ran a cable from my battery directly to the constant input. I still got the same when the ignition is off and key removed it looses all settings.

Im honestly at a loss, updated to the latest firmware even tried just wiring the red and yellow wires together but I dont want the screen to be on 24/7.

Anyone out there know their stereos or had this issue before?